# How to get updated automatically WPF TreeViewItems with values based on .Net class properties?

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged, treeviewitem

Good morning. 
I have a class with data derived from InotifyPropertyChange. The data come from a background thread, which searches for files with certain extension in certain locations. Public property of the class reacts to an event OnPropertyChange by updating data in a separate thread. Besides, there are described in XAML TreeView, based on HierarhicalDataTemplates. Each TextBlock inside templates supplied ItemsSource = "{Binding FoundFilePaths, Mode = OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated = True}".

```
 <TreeView  x:Name="FoundFiles_TreeView"  Opacity="15" Background="White"   BorderThickness="5" FontFamily="Arial" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="360" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF539DBE" TargetUpdated="FoundFiles_TreeView_TargetUpdated">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle >
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.Tag" Value="InfoNode" />
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Brown"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType = "{x:Type lightvedo:FilesInfoStore}"  ItemsSource="{Binding FoundFilePaths, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
                    <!--Здесь указываются узлы дерева-->
                    <StackPanel x:Name ="TreeNodeStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,5,5,5" TargetUpdated="TextBlockExtensions_TargetUpdated">
         <TextBlock.Text>
          <MultiBinding StringFormat="Files with Extension  {0}">
           <Binding Path="FileExtension"/>
          </MultiBinding>
         </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <Button x:Name="OpenFolderForThisFiles" Click="OnOpenFolderForThisFiles_Click" Margin="5, 3, 5, 3" Width="22" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0.5">
                            <Image Source="images\Folder.png" Height="16" Width="20" >
                            </Image>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type lightvedo:FilePathsStore}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FilePaths, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" TargetUpdated="OnTreeViewNodeChildren_Update" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeView.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform AngleX="-0.083"/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-0.249"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TreeView.RenderTransform>
            <TreeView.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF74591F" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF9F7721" Offset="1" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFD9B972" Offset="0.49" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TreeView.BorderBrush>
        </TreeView>
```

Q: Why is the data from a class derived from INotifyPropertyChange does not affect the display of tree items. Do I understand: The interface will make INotifyPropertyChange be automatically redrawn TreeViewItems or do I need to manually carry out this operation? Currently TreeViewItems not updated and PropertyChamged always null. A feeling that no subscribers to the event OnPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set the `NotifyOnTargetUpdated`.

Instead, make sure to raise the [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event (with the appropriate property-name passed with the [`PropertyChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.propertychangedeventargs.aspx) passed to the handler) on the parent entity each time the paths collection is updated, or have the navigation property be an implementation of [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx).

Comment: With this OnPropertyChanged ("FoundFilePaths") is all right. Event occurs each time a data class that inherits from INotifyPropertyChange updated in a background thread. Itself a visual representation of the TreeView does not change.

Comment: Maybe try to get the parent `TreeViewItem` and call it's `Items.Refresh()`.

Comment: The most important thing here: public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }    handler is always null.

Comment: In order to perform Items.Refresh () need to know that the event occurred PropertChanged in the class data. Namely, this event TreeView does not respond.

Comment: TreeView does automatically update its visual representation in response to the PropertyChanged events in the class from which the data arrives?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Shimmy. It seems I have missed some important thing in the theory. One of my data classes include other as ObservableCollection<FirstClass> and inside TreeView DataTemplates I have refernce to two different classes: lightvedo:FilesInfoStore and lightvedo:FilePathsStore. But both of this captured the PropertyChange Event. Or maybe the problem is a separate thread? And Where does the reference to the handler? Unfortunately the implementation of a mechanism for signing events XAML element is not clear to me.

Comment: Are you sure that the OnPropertyChanged is called on **current thread**?

Comment: Try `Dispatcher.Invoke(list.Refresh());`

Comment: Hmmm. I think OnPropertyChanged is called from BackgroundThread.

Comment: It seems correct to call the asynchronous method BeginInvoke () to update the interface?

Comment: I can not just call the Refresh (). I need to replace ItemsSource for TreeViewItems, otherwise nothing new in the TreeView, I do not see it.

Comment: `var treeViewItem = (TreeViewItem) TreeView.Items.ItemContainerGenerator(item); treeViewItem.Items.Refresh();`
Maybe wrap the second line with `Dispatcher.Invoke` (or `BeginInvoke`).

Comment: But I would first worry to make sure that `OnPropertyChanged("MyCollection")` is called on the main thread when the `MyCollection` count changes, or if MyCollection implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, `CollectionChanged` should be fired.

Comment: I think INotifyCollectionChanged is very good idea. I did not know about that interface. It is never too late to learn :)

Comment: I hope it's going to help you. Don't forget to vote / mark question as answered if it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason.
My background thread that constantly scans the folder creates a new instance of the data class derived from INotifyPropertyChanged, which serves as a source for TreeViewItems (ItemsSource). This principle is chosen because it is impossible to predict what should be done with a collection of files found: add a new item, remove an existing or edit an existing. If I ever intended to substitute ItemsSource trick with PropertyChange does not work. So for me the only solution was to call from the separate (background, scanning folders) thread Refresh() method for TreeViewItems.

```
public delegate void RefreshTreeViewItemsDelegate(); 

Dispatcher.FromThread(_guiThread).BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new RefreshTreeViewItemsDelegate (RefreshTreeItems)) 

// Some code ommited

private void RefreshTreeItems()
{
   _popupWindow.FoundFiles_TreeView.ItemsSource = _treeViewNodesItems;
   _popupWindow.FoundFiles_TreeView.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Use of this situation with these classes inherited from INotifyPropertyChanged useless. ItemsControl, you bind to this class expects only add, delete or change items, but not replace ItemsSource a new instance of the data class.

Comment: So you do not update items, but add newly created ones? That is updating a collection, which you are binded to, i.e. your _treeViewNodesItems should implement IObservableCollection interface, or just declare it as BindingList<T>. Use INotifyPropertyChanged for the items in treeview, if you want them to reflect changes, obviously it won't work for new items.